# How to create a Live (AJAX) Search in AMP with Laravel Backend?

Tags: ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest, amp-html

I am currently struggling with the AMP-Framework. 
I am trying to code a similar Live Search experience like seen on Pinterest. (Autofill and AJAX data request), yet I am not figuring out how to code it for LARAVEL in combination with AMP.

What I tried so far: AMP (XMLHttpRequest) for the form and trying to list results with the amp-list, which does not work due to Laravels blade design layout.

My Code:

```html
<form method="get"
      action-xhr="{{ route('search')}}"
      target="_top">
      {{csrf_field()}}
 <div class="search" on="tap:search_output.show,x.show">
  <input type="text" class="searchbox" id="searchBoxInput" name="searchBoxInput" placeholder="Search" value="">
  #pay attention to no submit input field!
 </div>
</form>
<div id="search_results">
        #show results via amp-list or 
        <template type="amp mustache"></template>
</div>
```

I made sure that all the scripts are loaded correctly. 
I would prefer the amp solution rather than using the amp-script to make a workaround.
Helpful explanations are welcome with references to the AMP-Documentation and examples for Laravel

Comment: where is the script?

Comment: the ajax script is here : function search_data(search_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search/' + search_value,
        method: 'POST'
    }).done(function(response){
        $('#search_results').html(response);
    });
}